# Print raw string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, escaping

I have a column which contains special characters. I want to print those characters as they are (escaped).

I tried [Quote](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_quote). But that didn't help me.

This is what I want:

```
select col1 from table;

"Don't\ttype\tlike\this\n\nNot acceptable"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a built in function for this but you could try using replace:

```
select replace( replace(col1, '\t', '\\t'), '\n', '\\n' ) from table;
```

Obviously you will need to add more chained replaces for each other escape character you wish to un-escape.

By adding a \ before the escape string, you convert it to a string literal.

Comment: This is more like a hit and trial method. I don't know which special characters exist in the column. If I could get a raw string I would be able to see all special characters that might be hidden somewhere.